# How define C++ string macro in Visual Studio Code tasks.json?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c-preprocessor, settings

In a Windows `cmd` command line window the following comand

```
g++ -std=c++14 -o test.exe "-DSTRING_MACRO=\"Hello world!\"" test.cc
```

compiles the test program in a **MinGW** environment well.

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{ const std::string string { STRING_MACRO };

  std::cout << string << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Which syntax for the macro definition must be used in *tasks.json*?

A simple mechanic conversion to an equivalent json (and a lot of other tries with less or more escapes) didn't work, e. g.

```
"\"-DSTRING_MACRO=\\\"Hello world\\\"\""
```

neither in the `args` Array nor in the `command` in *tasks.json*.

Answer (score 1):

It is well documented. Bellow is the example.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++14",
                "-o", "test.exe",
                "-DSTRING_MACRO='\"Hello world!\"'",
                "test.cc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Read here for further information, for example an input file can be a variable, containing a current file: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: This was my first try also, but it doesn't work with error message
*g++.exe: error: world! No such file or directory*
because the space isn't handled as expected.

Even dropping the space with
`"-DSTRING_MACRO=\"Hello_world!\""`
will not work with error message
*<command-line>:0:14: error 'Hello_world' was not declared in this scope>* which means, that string quotes are discarded at the way through the tool chain.
The provided solution is exactly my until now unsolved problem.

Comment: This error comes from the compiler itself. In first glance it looked like error came from the command line. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This I also tried already before, it leads to error message *<command-line> :0:14: error: stray '\' in program*. The only error source is the macro definition in *tasks.json*, because the program compiles, if I define `STRING_MACRO` inside *test.cc* and comment out in *tasks.json* for compiling in Visual Studio Code. Command line in Windows command line window works well. Updating MinGW to todays current release 7.3.0 didn't change anything. I used as workaround definition in the .cc file, but this is not, what I really need